# adding options to select

Tags: javascript, html

Hi i tried adding options to select through javascript in two ways, neither worked:

one way:

```
function addYear() {
    var currentYear = new Date().getFullYear();
    var legalWorkingAge = currentYear - 16;
    var select = document.getElementById("Year");
    for (var i = legalWorkingAge; i >= 1900; i--) {
        try {select.add(new Option(i,0), null);} // standards compliant; doesn't work in IE  
        catch(ex) {select.add(new Option(i,0));}    // IE only
        }//for
} //addYear
```

second way:

```
function addMonth() {
    var select = document.getElementById("Month");
    for (var i = 1; i <= 12; i++) {
        var option = document.createElement('option');
        option.text = option.value = i;
        select.add(option, 0);
    } //for
} //addMonth
```

i used

```
<body onload="addDate()">
```

addDate():

```
function addDate() {
    addMonth();
    addYear();
}
```

html:

```
<select id="Month" name="Month">
</select>
<select id="Year" name="Year">
</select>
```

any ideas? Tnx for the help :D

Answer (score 0):

This will work in all browsers

[<kbd>**Live Demo**</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/2pH57/)

```
window.onload=function() {
  addYear();
}

function addYear() {
    var currentYear = new Date().getFullYear();
    var legalWorkingAge = currentYear - 16;
    var select = document.getElementById("Year");
    for (var i = legalWorkingAge; i >= 1900; i--) {
        select.options[select.options.length]=new Option(i,i);
    }//for
} //addYear
```

Comment: What does that mean? Errors? What?